# Negate checkbox selection status on multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I have a big form with several checkboxes, having names chkbx0..chkbxN for them (N is known by PHP code which generates the form). I want to create a link-like entity which will invert  the checked status (so, what was checked becomes unchecked and vice versa) for all the checkboxes when it's clicked. So basically I am interested in a javascript function which has a parameter (the "N") and does the work, and I would call it something like this:

```
    <p>You can reverse checkboxes <a href="javascript:chkbxsnegate(<?php echo $n; ?>);">by clicking here</a>.</p>
```

The checkboxes are something like these:

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx0">
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkbx1">
    ...
```

I use the parameter "N", because there can be more checkboxes, but I only need to invert checked status only till "N".

Please suggest me a javascript code fragment to implement function "chkbxsnegate". Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work in most browsers, except IE7 and below (but it works in IE8 and 9)

```
function chkbxsnegate(n) {
    var qsa = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=chkbx"+n+"]"),
        l = qsa.length, i;
    for( i=0; i<l; i++) qsa[i].checked = !qsa[i].checked;
}
```

Comment: I can alter it to work in IE7 and below, using `getElementsByName()`, if you need me to. Let me know if you do.

Answer (score 4):

There is a shorter solution:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
  $(this).prop('checked', !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Even shorter:

```
$("[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    this.checked = !this.checked;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Jquery

```
$('input[name^=chkbx]').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
     $(this).prop('checked', false);
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).prop('checked', true);
  }
});
```

Comment: Code `$(this).is(':checked')` can be replaced with `$(this).prop('checked')`. I think it is nice. [http://api.jquery.com/prop/](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood you need to reverse the `checked` attribute until `n^th` element (from `0` to `n^th` included)

```
var chkbxsnegate = function(n) {
   var cbox = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"][name^="chkbx"]');
   while (n--) {
      cbox[n].checked = !cbox[n].checked;
   }
}
```

Example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wHPnA/

Answer (score -1):

You should use jQuery to inverse the checkboxes.

```
$('a#cb-inverse').click(function() {
 $('input.my_cb').each(function() {
   $(this).is(':checked') ? $(this).removeAttr('checked') : $(this).attr('checked','checked');
 });
});
```

See [this link](http://markojakic.net/jquery-checkboxes-inverse-selection) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but I am a beginner with average JS as well, JQuery is totally alien for me :) And I thought what I want can be written with just a few lines of "regular" JS which work on virtually every browser even without using jQuery etc. Since I need just this functionality I have the feeling it's a bit overkill to depend on advanced frameworks. But I can be wrong here, as I've told, I am not an expert in this at all :)

Comment: JQuery will work on every browser, you'll find you need to write a lot more code to do it for every browser without JQuery, thats the point of it.

Comment: function picflipselneg(n) { for(a=0;a<pages;a++) { e=document.getElementById("chkbx"+a); e.checked=!e.checked; } }

this seems to be OK now. Do you mean that it's not so well supported solution throught the browsers, and jQuery would be more "cross platform"? I am still confused now that a basic task like this cannot be done without involving some extra framework, but I am quite sure you are more experienced in JS than me ...